# How to blocking access to some libraries using Android Fat AAR

Tags: java, android, aar, android-module

I can get an aar output by connecting multiple modules using Fat AAR. But there are modules in these multi modules that should not be accessed by the application. I am using this library for fat aar https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android

If I use implementation, the corresponding classes are not accessible in the application layer, but a runtime crash (class not found exception). If I use Embed, classes that the application layer should not be able to access will be accessible.

Is there a solution to this problem without making a single module?